# routing packets to default gateway

Tags: networking, routing

I've got two networks (NET0, NET1) and my default gatway to ISP is in NET0. Routing between NET0 and NET1 is done by an Ubuntu Server (GATEWAY1). Everything works fine, all hosts in NET0 and NET1 are reachable from both networks. But if a host in NET1 tries to open a connection to a host in Internet (ex. 8.8.8.8) the connection fails. If I do the same on GATEWAY1 itself everything is fine. I made some dumps on GATEWAY1 and saw, that no packets are forwarded to router ISP. The routing table on GATEWAY1:

```
$ ip route list

default via 192.168.178.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.178.21 metric 303 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link src 169.254.251.133 metric 202 
192.168.178.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.178.21 metric 303 
192.168.179.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.179.1
```

On default gateway ISP in NET0 is a static route configured to NET1 via GATEWAY1.

The only way I get this work is by using NAT on GATEWAY1, but NAT is already done by the default gateway.

Any ideas what's wrong? I would appreciate any help.

My network looks like this

[image: this]

My firewall config at the moment:

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

If I flush all rules, I have the situation described above, all hosts in both connected network are reachable, but no host in Internet. I can also ping hosts in NET1 from GATEWAY GW/NAT. If I run a tcpdump on GATEWAY1 while pinging 8.8.8.8 from a host in NET1, I can see incomping pakets but no outgoing packets to GW/NAT.

Comment: Did you update `/etc/sysctl.conf` to allow ipv4 forwarding?

Comment: Yes I did. net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

Comment: What's your firewall configuration on Gateway1?

Comment: If i run iptables --flush I would expect that also all packets to hosts not in NET0 will be forwarded to GW/NAT by GATEWAY1 (-> default via 192.168.178.1 dev wlan0). But only packets to NET0 and NET1 are forwared.